# In JPA how can i bind Y N to Boolean type

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to bind Boolean variable to VARCHAR(1) Y/N in MySQL using JPA annotations ?

I am using below mapping`@Basic
  @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR", length = 1)
  private Boolean active;`

which is throwing exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [A] did not match expected type [java.lang.Boolean (n/a)]
```

so I figured out the reason for error, it was because I was passing 'Y' as a parameter to named query.

```
params.put("isActive", "Y");
```

but now when I changed it to

```
params.put("isActive", Boolean.TRUE);
```

the query is not returning any result it seems it's passing 'true' as a parameter to the query.

Can somebody tell me how to correctly map this ?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Safest way is to define an [`AttributeConverter`](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/types.html#typeconverter) that maps Boolean to String and that maps to "Y" or "N". Then define your Boolean field to use that `AttributeConverter`.

Comment: @Convert is not available this is part of which library ?

Comment: Part of standard JPA 2.1, as that linked page tells you

Comment: I am using jboss 6 EAP which should have it all, please check out the updated post with maven dependency. Won't this contain the required dependency ?

Comment: It isn't my "job" to check your dependencies content. You should know if you are using JPA 1, JPA 2.0, JPA 2.1. JavaEE6 likely is JPA 2.0. But then you should have put that in the question so people have basis for answering